# Errores en Java add y get

Tags: java

Buenas noches,
Me he topado con dos errores que desconozco cómo solucionar, he probado todo lo que sé y preguntado a amigos, pero ni con esas. El código es este:

```
public int getButacasDisponiblesSesion (int sesion){
   return this.sesiones.get(sesion -1).getButacasDisponiblesSesion();
   }

public ButacasContiguas recomendarButacasContiguas (int noButacas, int 
sesion){
     return this.sesiones.get(sesion-
1).recomendarButacasContiguas(noButacas,sesion);   
   }
public void comprarEntradasRecomendadas (int sesion, ButacasContiguas 
butacas){
  this.sesiones.get(sesion - 1).comprarEntradasRecomendadas(sesion,butacas);
}
public void incluirSesion(String horaSesion){
  int pos = 0;
while (pos < this.sesiones.size() && 
this.sesiones.get(pos).getHora().copareTo(horaSesion)){
  pos ++;
}
this.sesiones.add(pos, new Sesion(horaSesion, this.filas, this.columnas));

}
```

Y los errores que me saltan son:

> The method getButacasDisponiblesSesion(int) in the type sala is not applicable >for the arguments().
>
> The method add(int, sala) in the type ArrayList  is not applicable for the arguments (int, Sesion).

Cabe decir que tengo getButacasDisponibesSesion definido en otra clase Sesion.

Muchísimas gracias de antemano :-)

Si necesitan más información pídanla, soy nuevo aquí y no sé si es la mejor forma de preguntar y de explicarme.

Comment: Esta pregunta me suena de otra que fue cerrada. En los comentarios a la anterior pregunta ya se te decía que, cuando llamas a un método tienes que pasarle la cantidad y el tipo de datos que dicho método espera. Así que si tienes este método: `public int getButacasDisponiblesSesion (int sesion){` como ves entre paréntesis el método espera un entero `int sesion`. Si luego llamas a ese método haciendo: `.getButacasDisponiblesSesion()` ¿Dónde está el entero que espera el método? Debería ser algo como: `.getButacasDisponiblesSesion(nVariableoNumeroEntero)`. Eso es algo básico de cualquier lenguaje.

Comment: Si estoy de acuerdo con A. Cedano, por otro lado al parecer el error no es originado en el bloque de codigo que ha compartido.

Comment: @Tecnologer creo que es un fallo de Eclipse en el caso del get [enlace] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964430/node-gettextcontent-is-undefined-in-node), pero no sé qué pasa con el add.

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias, he conseguido solucionar otro error gracias a tu ayuda :-)

Comment: Creo que por ayuda a la comunidad pudieras explicar en una respuesta el la solucion

Comment: @Tecnologer cómo? Lo siento, no te he entendido

Comment: Si, tu mismo crea una respuesta donde expliques a detalle la solucion que hiciste, si esta muy extenso, has una solucion resumida y coloca los links que te ayudaron

Comment: @Tecnologer de acuerdo, pero... ¿sabes cómo solucionar el problema del add? Es que me está volviendo loco. Muchas gracias por tu atención.

Comment: Debe ser algo relacionado al mismo motivo del `get`, pero la verdad no se tengo una solucion precisa.

Comment: @DanielPérez Quizás este curso pueda ser de utilidad: [**Curso de JAVA Básico Gratis**](https://codigofacilito.com/cursos/JAVA). +@A.Cedano ;)

Comment: El método `add` espera como parámetro un `int` y un `sala` y tu has pasado como parámetro un `int` y un `Sesion`

Answer (score 0):

El problema del add del ArrayList **creo** que está en que el método debe recibir un solo parámetro y este ha de ser del tipo del ArrayList definido.
En tu ejemplo supongo que tu lista sea de objetos sesion y por lo tanto el parámetro pos, sobra.